# Template10 NavigationService is null

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

This is my App.xaml.cs

```
[Bindable]
sealed partial class App : Template10.Common.BootStrapper
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SplashFactory = (e) => new Views.Splash(e);

        var _settings = SettingsService.Instance;
        RequestedTheme = _settings.AppTheme;
        CacheMaxDuration = _settings.CacheMaxDuration;
        ShowShellBackButton = _settings.UseShellBackButton;
    }

    public override async Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
        {
            var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
            await statusBar.HideAsync();
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage)); // Exception here
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Every time i launch the app i get this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException verificata
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

NavigationService is always null.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I tested with your code, it works well. The code you've posted is right. I think the problem may not be here. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? Or you can test your code with a Minimal Template 10 project, it should be able to work.

Comment: If i create a new project this code works fine

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming back to this, I run across issue and realized that if I kept the minimum version of the project 10586 the problem goes away.

Comment: You are a life saver! This did the trick for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I updated the Target min version of the project to Fall Creators Update (see `project properties`).

After reading [this](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1646) thread I fixed the issue by updating the `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget dependency from version `11.x.x` to `10.0.3`.

So just to be clear I downgraded the version of the `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue, but inside of `ViewModel` not in App.xaml.cs.

So `NavigationService` was null when I defined and initialized my `ViewModel` as property in code behind of view.

Solution is to define ViewModel in xaml (`<Page.DataContext>`) then everything works like a charm.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but I am having this issue as well.  Can you please explain exactly what you did to fix this?  I would really appreciate it!